# Docker Build Issue: No Such File or Directory

Tags: docker, containers, docker-build

I was attempting to dockerize my node project backed by AWS lambda, But when I actually run the file, it gives me the following error.

```
 => CACHED [build 3/6] COPY . .                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [build 4/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [build 5/6] RUN npm run build:ts                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [build 6/6] RUN npm prune --production                                                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [serve 3/6] COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/ /usr/src/app/dist/                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [serve 4/6] COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/views/ /usr/src/app/views/                                                         0.0s
 => ERROR [serve 5/6] COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules/ /usr/src/app/node_modules/                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [serve 6/6] COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/package.json /usr/src/app/package.json                                             0.0s
------
 > [serve 3/6] COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/ /usr/src/app/dist/:
------
------
 > [serve 4/6] COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/views/ /usr/src/app/views/:
------
------
 > [serve 5/6] COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules/ /usr/src/app/node_modules/:
------
------
 > [serve 6/6] COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/package.json /usr/src/app/package.json:
------
failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount486916116/usr/src/app: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount486916116/usr/src/app: no such file or directory
```

here is the code for my docker file

```
FROM node:12 as build

WORKDIR /usr/scr/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build:ts
RUN npm prune --production

FROM node:12 as serve

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=build "/usr/src/app/dist/" "/usr/src/app/dist/"
COPY --from=build "/usr/src/app/views/" "/usr/src/app/views/"
COPY --from=build "/usr/src/app/node_modules/" "/usr/src/app/node_modules/"
COPY --from=build "/usr/src/app/package.json" "/usr/src/app/package.json"

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "dist/app.js"]
```

as well as the package.json under the same package dockerfile resides

```
{
    "name": "express-webserver",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "",
    "scripts": {
        "build:ts": "tsc",
        "docker:build": "docker build -t dtuckernet/poc-webserver .",
        "docker:run" : "docker run -p 8080:8080 -e SERVER_PORT=8080 -e API_BASE=https://id6ualpxkc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ -d dtuckernet/poc-webserver"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "ejs": "^3.1.8",
        "express": "^4.18.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
        "@types/node": "^17.0.35",
        "typescript": "^4.6.4"
    }
}
```

The folder structure of my code looks like:

[image]

Can anyone help me to see what happened? I can include github link for this project as well if the above info is not adequate. https://github.com/jaydenyen123/typescript-cdk/tree/master/containers/webserver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misspelled `src` in the first `WORKDIR` statement in the Dockerfile.

```
WORKDIR /usr/scr/app
```